# Merge two sorted double vectors using different comparision function

Tags: c++, vector, merge, stl, numeric

I have two sorted `std::vector<double>` containers. Now I need to merge both vectors to a new sorted container, with the restriction,
that two values should be considered equal if and only if `std::fabs(a-b)<1.e-6` holds. This problem pops up plenty of times in our
code and I'm looking for the neatest solution.

My first attempt was:

```
std::vector<double> mergeTimeLists(const std::vector<double>& sorted1, const std::vector<double>& sorted2) {    
    auto cmp = [&](double a, double b)->bool { return std::fabs(a - b) > 1e-6 && a < b; };
    std::set<double, decltype(cmp)> set(cmp);
    std::copy(sorted1.begin(), sorted1.end(), std::inserter(set, set.begin()));
    std::copy(sorted2.begin(), sorted2.end(), std::inserter(set, set.begin()));
    std::vector<double> ret;
    std::copy(set.begin(), set.end(), std::back_inserter(ret));
    return ret;
}
```

After consulting again the docs of the STL I came up with:

```
std::vector<double> mergeTimeLists1(const std::vector<double>& sorted1, const std::vector<double>& sorted2) {
    std::vector<double> ret;
    std::merge(sorted1.begin(), sorted1.end(), sorted2.begin(), sorted2.end(), std::back_inserter(ret));
    ret.erase(std::unique(ret.begin(), ret.end(), [&](double a, double b)->bool { return std::fabs(a - b) < 1e-6; }),ret.end());
    return ret;
}
```

This is my test:

```
int main(int argc, char** args) {
    {
        auto ret = mergeTimeLists({ 0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.34 }, { 0.05,0.10000001 });
        std::copy(ret.begin(), ret.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, " "));
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    {
        auto ret = mergeTimeLists1({ 0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.34 }, { 0.05,0.10000001 });
        std::copy(ret.begin(), ret.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, " "));
    }

}
```

Does anyone has some ideas for improvements?

**Revised question**

Seemingly, I was unable to state my question completely clear and unambiguous. It turned out, that what I actually wanted was something slightly different.

Assume, that I have two sorted `std::vector<double>` containers `s1` and `s2`. I wanted to create a new sorted container `s` containing all values in `s1` and some values in `s2`, whereas are value `v` from `s2` is only contained in `s` if and only if there is no value `u` in `s1`, such that `std::fabs(u-v)<1e-6`.

Hence, I only want the values of `s2` to be in the resulting container `s`, if there are not too close to some values in `s1`.

I'm very sorry for not stating my question so clear beforehand and I'm really delighted about the feedback I already got so far. Maybe there are still ideas I can get from here?

Comment: *"two values should be considered equal if and only if `std::fabs(a-b)<1.e-6` holds"* This is not a valid equivalence relation, and so cannot be used for sorting. It's not transitive - it's possible that `a` is "close enough" to `b` and `b` is "close enough" to `c`, but `a` is not "close enough" to `c`. Why can't you just sort using the normal less-than comparison? Close numbers will naturally end up next to each other anyway.

Comment: A permissible ordering relation would be `std::round(a * 1.e6) < std::round(b * 1.e6)`. Or you could switch to a decimal representation

Answer (score 1):

The vectors are sorted.  The result is to be a sorted vector as well.

Using `std::merge()` is a good start, but your example falls short of optimal performance in two ways:

1. You neglect to reserve capacity in the returned vector before the merge.
2. You insert all elements during the merge, then erase unwanted elements after it.

The first is trivially addressed:

```
ret.reserve(std::max(sorted1.size(), sorted2.size()));
```

The second can be solved by changing the output iterator given to `std::merge()`.  Instead of `std::back_inserter(ret)`, create your own `unique_inserter(ret)`, like this:

```
struct unique_inserter
    : std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<double>>
{
    typedef std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<double>> base;

    unique_inserter(std::vector<double>& out) : base(out) {}

    unique_inserter& operator=(const double& value)
    {
        if (container->empty() || std::fabs(container->back() - value) > 1e-6)
            container->push_back(value);
        return *this;
    }

    // remove this if not using C++11
    unique_inserter& operator=(const double&& value)
    {
        if (container->empty() || std::fabs(container->back() - value) > 1e-6)
            container->push_back(std::move(value));
        return *this;
    }
};
```

This is like `std::back_inserter` but does nothing if a new value is equivalent to the last one.  This way, unwanted values are never inserted, and do not need to be erased later.

Comment: The two vectors are expected to contain mainly distinct values, so `ret.reserve(sorted1.size() + sorted2.size());` is more appropriate

Comment: @Caleth: Maybe so.  I'm curious how you know what OP's real data are expected to contain, though.  How did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: The example data they gave fits that pattern. The post merge result omits only 1 element

Comment: @Caleth: Sure, but IME examples often don't model the real distribution of inputs.  Anyway, your comment is well noted, but it won't make a big difference (at most one resize).

Comment: Many thanks for this fantastic solution. I wouldn't come up with the idea of deriving from `std::back_insert_iterator`. Even seems, that I understand better now, what I wanted to achieve. Still there seems a problem for me. I copied the solution, an for some reason the `operator=` of the `unique_inserter` is never called. (Just added a `std::cout` inside). Am I using it wrong?

Comment: @Aleph0: I had left out the rvalue-reference version of `operator=`.  I've added it to the answer now (the two methods can be combined somehow, an exercise for the reader).  Try that.  I guess the base class rvalue-reference one was being called.  If it still doesn't work, change the inheritance to private and do "using" to expose operator*, operator++.